# Python Argparser make argument mutually exclusive

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I am trying to use the `argparse` in my project. And I have two few arguments which I would like to mutually exclusive to other arguments.

**Code**

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='List keys in S3 bucket for prefix')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--bucket', help='S3 Bucket', required=True)

date_parser = parser.add_argument_group("for date")
date_parser.add_argument('-n', '--last_modified_min', default=None, type=valid_datetime, help='Filter s3 content by minimum last modified date')
date_parser.add_argument('-x', '--last_modified_max', default=None, type=valid_datetime, help='Filter s3 content by maximum last modified date')

time_parser = parser.add_argument_group("for time")
time_parser.add_argument("-m", '--modified_time', help="")
time_parser.add_argument("-t", '--modified_time_type', choices=("minutes", "hours", "days"), help="")
```

How can I configure such that, user can input either from `time_parser` group or `date_parser` group but not from both. 
i.e. Following should be invalid. as `-x` is part of `date_parser`.

> ```
> python test.py -b aa -m 1 -t hour -x 2020-01-01
> ```

**Update:**

I came up with this. However, it doesn't look elegant.

```py
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if bool(args.modified_time) ^ bool(args.modified_time_type):
        parser.error("--modified_time and --modified_time_type must be given togather")

    if (bool(args.modified_time) and bool(args.modified_time_type)) and (args.last_modified_min or args.last_modified_max):
        parser.error("--last_modified_min or --last_modified_max can't be given with --modified_time")
```

Comment: `argument_group` is only for help display.  It does not have any sort of 'multual-inclusivity' properties.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do this before and I believe it is not supported.

[`add_mutually_exclusive_group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group) only allows choosing a single argument from the group, and if you try to nest them it just flattens the group.

You could use [`add_subparsers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers) to choose whether you are in date or time mode, but that makes the interface of the script pretty gross.

The best solution I know of is to handle the logic manually right after `parse_args`, and call [`parser.error`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.error) if something is wrong.